# How do I get the memory fragment on Galata Tower?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

There's a memory fragment on a wooden platform sticking out of the side of Galata Tower:

[image: what up lil memfrag]

How the heck do I get to it?

As far as I can tell, there is no route to climb up to or around it (unless I'm missing something obvious). I tried climbing above it and dropping down onto it, but when I let go of the wall above I plummet into a hay pile below instead of down to the platform (which is actually good since in order to get above the platform you have to get high enough that the fall would probably desynchronize you).

So how do I get this darn thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried jumping off of a higher part of the tower, and then using a parachute to angle yourself back around?  The parachute is a bit tricky, but invaluable when trying to reach odd locations like that.

I don't think I have this fragment yet, but I do think it might also be possible to jump off the top of another nearby tower to get the right angle for the parachute.

Note that you can't parachute if you're doing a Leap of Faith, so don't jump off any areas where birds are roosting or circling (or towards a haystack/rosebush/etc), lest you swan dive into a rose bush or hay bale instead.

If you're dropping down off of some impossible height, you can always press B to hookblade anything that's grabbable on the way down.  No matter how far you fall, you'll always avoid damage if you can hook a platform on the way down.  If you fall somewhat close to the platform, try mashing B as you fall to see if you can't grab onto it.

Hooking a platform 2 feet off the ground from a deadly fall without tearing your arm out of its socket?  Ezio's all like, *What? I'm an assassin.  We're **so bad.***

Comment: Oh duh, parachutes. I will play around with them next time I play.

Comment: I did this successfully with the parachute, yeah.

Comment: Yeah, using the parachute is the only way to get that one AFAIK.

Comment: Also, you don't necessarily need to see the birds to do a leap of faith, just merely jumping in the direction of a haystack/bush will trigger it.

Comment: That's what I found with my attempt at dropping onto the plat - I can't mash B to break my fall because I'm stuck in the Leap of Faith animation, even though there are no birdies in sight.

Comment: I'll test my theory at some point, but I think if hang off the side and press B instead of leaping off, you might end up in the "falling" instead of "diving" animation, and be able to latch or parachute to break your fall.  Just left that in there as a possible solution, it seems like the parachutes are the way to go.

Comment: I believe I was hanging off the wall when I tried to drop, not standing on something. Can't remember for sure but I think I was dangling from my hookblade. Corroboration would be good though.

Comment: @agent86: dropping from hanging from an edge near a stack will always do a drop (i.e., fall backwards) straight into it.  A nice side effect to that is that it counts as a leap of faith.  (this is a great way to get the 40 leaps necessary for the faction challenges, just find a bale near a short ledge)

Comment: If you try to jump off on the side that the fragment is on you automatically do a leap of faith.

Comment: Yeah, I spent a good 20 minutes trying to find a way to fall downward and grab that platform, but the game seems to want to orient me towards the haystack.  Darn you game, trying to keep me from slamming into a wooden platform at a lethal velocity!

Answer (score 1):

Climb the Galata Tower all the way to the top. You will find a stack of hay there and birds where you usually perform a leap of faith. Stand a bit from it to avoid doing the leap and jump from the Tower. Open your parachute and maneuver it close to the tower - once you are close, drop, and that's it!